# JavaScript Compression String

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Defined a function that takes one argument (a string) and returns another string.

Input example: `aabcc`

Output example: `a2bc2`

```js
function compressedString(message) {
    if (message.length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    var result = "";
    var count = 0;
    for (var n = 0; n < message.length; n++) {
        count++;
        if (message[n] != message[n+1]) {
            result += message[n] + count;
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(compressedString('aabcc'));
```

Output I am getting: a1b1c1
Looked over the code but don't seem to find what's wrong.

Comment: If there's nothing wrong, what is your question about?  Looks like you got a different string out of your function, which was your goal.

Comment: I am supposed to get the output a2bc2 instead of a1b1c1, it’s count the single character as well and I just want to count if there is repetition.

Comment: There seems to be no problem. Can you tell me about your question?

Comment: *"Output I am getting: a1b1c1..."* That **isn't** the output of the code in the question. The output of the code in the question is `a2b1c2`.

Comment: @ViktorM - I think the problem is the `1` after `b`.

Comment: See the output I get when running console.log ? I am getting a2b1c2 from an input of “aabcc”, which works, but I do not want for the function to count single character, just repeated ones. I am supposed to get a string and compressed it if there are repeated character. The output I am looking for from “aabcc” is “a2bc2” instead.

Answer (score 2):

Please change one line.

```
result += count > 1 ? message[n] + count : message[n];
```

If count is lower than 2, don't add count.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a [`Conditional operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to only append the count if it is greater than `1`.

```js
result += message[n] + (count > 1 ? count : '');
```

Full code:

```js
function compressedString(message) {
  if (message.length == 0) {
    return;
  }
  var result = '';
  var count = 0;
  for (var n = 0; n < message.length; n++) {
    count++;
    if (message[n] != message[n + 1]) {
      result += message[n] + (count > 1 ? count : '');
      count = 0;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(compressedString('aabcc'));
```

Comment: This! Thank you, that’s the output I was looking for, I really appreciate the help mate! Sorry for all the mistakes, I am still somewhat new to code.

Comment: @mufcod Make sure to mark the solution as accepted if it worked for you .

Answer (score 1):

Your function was actually returning: a2b1c2. If you want to return a2bc2 you just need an if to check if count is 1:

```
function compressedString(message) {
        if (message.length == 0) {
            return;
        }
        var result = "";
        var count = 0;
        for (var n = 0; n < message.length; n++) {
            count++;
            if (message[n] != message[n + 1]) {
                if (count == 1)
                    result += message[n]
                else {
                    result += message[n] + count;
                }
                count = 0;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have arr1 = [a1,b2,c1];
and you want to convert it into [abbc]

Javascript accepts only numbers in for loop. So if you take the elements of this array individually, in the cast of characters it won't run except in the case of all the numbers it will run. But don't use +(element) operator. Since characters will throw a NaN.

So you can approach it so easily like this:

```
function check(string){
    var new_string = "";
    for(let i=0; i < string.length; i++){
       let count = string[i];
       for(var j=0; j< count; j++){
          new_string = new_string + string[i];
       }
    }
    console.log(new_string);
}

check("a2b3c2");
```

good luck

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read up on [answering questions well](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering).  This seems neither to answer the question you're responding to, nor to log what's advertised.  (`check("a1b2c1") //=>"1221", instead of "abbc"`)